# change fish shell prompt based on hostname

Tags: bash, fish

How do I go about changing my fish shell prompt when I'm on a different machine via `ssh`.

I get it working with running a `set -q __fish_prompt_hostname` at the top of my prompt config and `"$__fish_prompt_hostname"` when I want to call it, but when I `ssh` to another machine it cannot find the hostname and display it.

I know in bash `$HOSTNAME` is the way to go, but with fish I'm not sure how to get the hostname. (I also would like to change the colors of my prompt based on the hostname due to some machines being more volatile than others.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can emulate bash by putting `set -x HOSTNAME (hostname)` in your *~/.config/fish/config.fish*. You may prefer to strip the domain name from it with `set -x HOSTNAME (hostname | string split -m1 '.')[1]`. That is what the `prompt_hostname` function does to set the `__fish_prompt_hostname` var.

Comment: Thanks this did the trick! The bash emulation is great. I got bass as well to do more bash stuff with fish since I still miss some of the good things about bash.